# Can't take global variable in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

When user click the button , the age is 50. After that, when sending data using nfc,the value of age is 0.0. Help! How I can solve it ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

String mone;
InputStream is =null;
double age;
double app=50.00,water=60.88,ban=35.55;
boolean app_b=true, water_b=true, ban_b=true;

private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        String te = new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
        mone=te;
        Log.e("value 2 ","val"+age); //age is 0.0 

    }
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.apple)
        app_b=false;
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.watermelon)
        water_b=false;
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.banana)
        ban_b=false;
}

public void aniStart(){
    // Next screen comes in from right.
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
    // Current screen goes out from left.
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
    // Display previous screen.
    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
}

public void submit(View v){

    if(v.getId() == R.id.button && (!app_b || !water_b || !ban_b)){
        if (!app_b)
            age=app;
        else if (!water_b)
            age=water;
        else   if (!ban_b)
            age=ban;
        aniStart();
        Log.e("Value","age:"+age); //age=50;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please select your fruit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Why age is 0.0 ?

UPDATE :

This app is actually receive data from another phone via NFC. Before tapping the phone , I click on the button and get the value 50. After that , I receive data from another phone and hold the string value in "te".

Comment: Because you never gave it another value before calling that log statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your variable is getting updated when button is clicked but if you want to assign a value to age when checking intent then you can pass a double in the Intent that started this activity using putExtra(String key, double value) in that intent.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm quite new to Android.

Comment: @joigu if thats what you're trying to do (after clicking the button the nfc code) then I'd suggest you move that block from onCreate() to onResume() and you can use a boolean to control the behavior i.e only if onClick() has been called then your nfc block shall run

Answer (score 0):

uhm `onCreate` gets called first and age has no value assigned.

Comment: How can I update the value of age after onClick is trigger. Thanks in advance.

Comment: K The value is changed to 50 after onClick. When I send data via NFC , the age is 0.0.  What's problem?

Comment: Send it in your `onClick` method? [Look here for the android activity lifecycle. That will tell you why you can't send it in your ´onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Age is showing up as 0.0 because:**

1. This is the default value given to an unassigned double in java(`double age; // age = 0.0`)
2. The `onCreate()` method runs as soon as your activity 'starts up' (before you can click your button) so the log statement will always print whatever value you initialize the age variable to (in this case that's 0.0).

Comment: Oncreate method doesn't runs the log statement as soon as my activity starts up. The Log.e which inside "IF" statement is trigger when I send it via NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in onClick():

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    Log.e("nfc","insidenfc"+age);  //age is 0.0
 }
```

Comment: try it public static double age = 0.0;

Comment: When you call the submit function?

Comment: It's just a button. I click on "r.id.apple" and then click submit button, age value should be 50. After that , I receive a string value from NFC and hold it in "te" variable.